# Jasmine, Karma, Mocking a Promise Properly

Tags: angular, jasmine

One of my Angular liabilities is being very new so this question may have an answer and I just don't know the terminology to use....my apologies.

My service endpoint:

```
//Initializes loading sort device config when the page is loaded
checkSortCfg(forceReload?: boolean): Promise<void>
{
    ...snip....

    let promise = self.sortApiSvc.getOut()
    
    ....snip.... 
    return promise;

}
```

API Service that gets called above:

```
getOut(): Promise<string[]> {
    const url = this.uriService.getAppServerUri('...');
    return this.http.get<any>(url).toPromise();
}
```

My unit test, I am leaving out the before each etc. as that all seems to be functioning properly.

My mock of the API call:

```
sortApiServiceCallSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj("SortApi", ["getOut"]);
sortApiServiceCallSpy.getOut.and.callFake(function () {
        return {
            then: function (callback) {
                return callback([
                    { value: new Observable<string[]>((observer) => { observer.complete(); }).toPromise() }
                ]);
            }
        };
    });
```

When I run the test and debug my mock comes back as undefined

> ReferenceError: promise is not defined.
>
> let promise = self.sortApiSvc.getOut()

So I must have the mocked return value wrong.

```
sortApiServiceCallSpy.getOut.and.callFake(function () {
        return {
            then: function (callback) {
                return callback([
                    { value: new Observable<string[]>((observer) => { observer.complete(); }).toPromise() }
                ]);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you try `sortApiServiceCallSpy.getOut.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(value));` ?

Comment: @AmitChigadani That worked. Why not make an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try out the following to return the mock `Promise`.

```
sortApiServiceCallSpy.getOut.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(value));
```